# Azure function reduce log on Application insight

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

When my system is running some time I got the connection error so I want to remove it from my Application Insign

It is possible If I want to remove the exception and trace come from EventProcessorHost error. You can see my insign log as below.

[image]

Comment: is the question "how do i make it not collect these in the future?"  or is the question "how do i get rid of the ones i have?"

Comment: @Hung Nguyen Duy,  hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is that you can use app insights [Purge api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/components/purge) to delete logs from `Exceptions` table and `Traces` table.

But the limitation is that you cannot specify such detailed filters, like the messages are from `EventProcessorHost` etc.

And the delete operation will be competed in 7 days in background, you should know these limitaions when using this api.

Answer (score 0):

If the question was "how do i not collect these in the future", I believe the information you are looking for is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd#configure-categories-and-log-levels

summary:

> Log configuration in host.json
>
> The host.json file configures how much logging a function app sends to Application Insights. For each category, you indicate the minimum log level to send

there are a lot of samples in the link above to turn on and off things of various levels, sources, sampling, batching and is probably too much to paste here and keep up to date